# Get specific text from 2 paragraphs in the same class using Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

I'm very new to Scrapy and I want to be able to extract both texts paragraph using Scrapy shell: "**Fintec, Cybersecurity**" and "**Serie C**"

[image: HTML]

If I run

```
response.css('div.card-body p.card-text strong::text').get()
```

I get 'Secteur' but I'm looking for '**Fintec, Cybersecurity**'.

for

```
response.css('div.card-body p.card-text::text').get()
```

I get '/n'

I've noticed if I use

```
response.css('div.card-body p.card-text:nth-child(3)').get()
```

I get < p class="card-text">\n**Round** : Série C\n < /p>
and for

```
response.css('div.card-body p.card-text:nth-child(2)').get()
```

I get

< p class="card-text">\n**Secteur** : Fintech, Cybersecurity\n < / p>

How do I get **Serie C** and **Fintech Cybersecurity**?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work... `'div.card-body p.card-text::text'` you just need to use either the `getall` or `extract` methods.

Here is an example I did in ipython:

```py
In [3]: html = '''<div class="card-body">
   ...:     <h3 class="card-title mb-1">L</h3>
   ...:     <p class="card-text">
   ...:         <strong>Secteur</strong>
   ...:         " : Fintech, Cybersecurity "
   ...:     </p>
   ...:     <p class="card-text">
   ...:         <strong>Round</strong>
   ...:         " : Serie C "
   ...:     </p>
   ...:     <p class="card-text">
   ...:         <small class="text-muted"> 2820 votes enregistres </small>
   ...:     </p>
   ...: </div>'''

In [4]: response = parsel.Selector(html)

In [5]: for p in response.css('div.card-body p.card-text::text').getall():
   ...:     text=''.join(p).strip()
   ...:     print(text)
   ...:

" : Fintech, Cybersecurity "

" : Serie C "
```